# How can I exit from the Ruby Pry session and continue on the next statement?

Tags: ruby, continue, pry

I use the Pry gem (http://pryrepl.org) to test my programs. Sometimes exceptions arise, so I use this syntax:

```
require "pry"    
begin
  statement 1
  statement 2 *
  statement 3
rescue => e
  binding.pry
end
```

When exception arise on "statement 2" I get a pry session in the rescue clause. I can examine my variables etc, "e.backtrace" show the cause of exception, and which line caused it, etc. Then I usually make some changes in the source file to avoid the exception next time. However I don't want to start my program again, because it is a long time to arrive again to the "statement 2". So my question is how can I exit the Pry session and continue my program on "statement 3"? If I try to type "continue" or "next" I get only error messages.

Comment: Have you tried to require 'pry-debugger' so that you can get the functionality you are indicating here?  Check https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger#pry-debugger-

Comment: Another gem of interest for you may be the Exception Explorer for Pry.  Check https://github.com/pry/pry-exception_explorer/wiki#recovering-from-exceptions

Comment: Oh, thx, I never heard any of them.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is how can I exit the Pry session and continue my
>   program on "statement 3"?

If pry-debugger won't work for you, how about:

```
require "pry"    

begin
  statement 1
  statement 2
rescue => e
  binding.pry
end

begin
  statement 3
rescue => e
  binding.pry
end
```

For example:

```
require 'pry'

def a
  puts 'a'
end

def b
  puts 'b'
  nil[1]
end

def c
  puts 'c'
end



begin
  a
  b
rescue => e
  binding.pry
end

begin
  c
rescue => e
  binding.pry
end
```

--output:--

```
~/ruby_programs$ r 1.rb 
a
b

From: /Users/7stud/ruby_programs/1.rb @ line 22 :

    17: 
    18: begin
    19:   a
    20:   b
    21: rescue => e
 => 22:   binding.pry
    23: end
    24: 
    25: begin
    26:   c
    27: rescue => e

[1] pry(main)> exit
c
~/ruby_programs$
```

Of course that won't work, if your question is really,

> If my program throws an error on a random line, how can I get pry to
>   continue execution on the next line?

...

> If I try to type "continue" or "next" I get only error messages.

Well execution is here:

```
require "pry" 

begin
  statement 1
  statement 2 *
  statement 3
rescue => e
  binding.pry   #<== Pry executed here
end
#<=== Next line to execute after rescue clause
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to change the source and continue execution after you do that. I would try to place the pry statement closer to statement 2 and then re-run.

```
statement 1
binding.pry
statement 2
statement 3
```